# Find out how long ago the windows computer woke up

Tags: windows-10, script, wake-on-lan, uptime

I have a backup server which gets waken up by a wake-on-lan packet, then pulls the files from the clients and then goes back to sleep again.

Sometimes I wake it up via WOL and want to keep it on for a couple of hours.

When in the meantime a backup gets triggered, then the backup script sends the server back to sleep, which I don't want, as I had the intention to send it to sleep manually.

I don't want to set/unset a flag in a file, but have the server know that this backup did start while the server was already on for at least a couple of minutes and therefore should not be sent to sleep.

I figured out that the network interface status dialog contains a "duration" field, which is a good indicator for how long this interface has been up, which equals the time the server has been awake.

How can I access that information programatically, preferably through a python script?

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Event Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363652(v=vs.85).aspx) tracks events like "system has resumed from sleep".

Check the Windows Dev Center example code on [Querying for Event Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363674(v=vs.85).aspx).

I've not used this first hand but you should be able to get there with Python too.