# How do I find out when the computer last woke in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, power, hibernate, wake-up

Came home from a multi day trip to find my Windows 10 PC on. The PC that I had put into hibernate when I left. So I got curious: how would I figure out **when** the PC last woke? The device was `HID Keyboard Device` which seems like an odd one to have woken the PC up from hibernate.

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer? I would check the Windows Logs (System).

Comment: What event am I looking for?

Comment: Maybe kernel-power events. There should be a fairly long list of events that all start near the same time when the system comes out of hibernation.

Comment: Try the free, no-installation tool from Nirsoft, TurnedOnTimesView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_turned_on_times.html, which just abstracts that data from the Windows Event Log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out how long ago the windows computer woke up](https://superuser.com/questions/1136628/find-out-how-long-ago-the-windows-computer-woke-up)